# Is NetflterSDK able to inject javascript into http stream?

Tags: firewall, wfp, packet-injection

I tried [netfiltersdk.com](http://netfiltersdk.com) , using their WFP driver to intercept HTTP traffic and block websites like Facebook. Works very well with their "PFHttpBlocker.exe 'facebook'" example.

I want to inject javascript into the HTTP stream to for example close the website or show an

```
alert('facebook blocked');
```

In the netfilterdsk [Protocol Filter Documentation](http://www.netfiltersdk.com/help/ProtocolFilters)

```
It is possible to update object content in dataPartAvailable and return DPCR_UPDATE_AND_BYPASS
```

Will it be possible to inject javascript then?

Comment: I saw that Komodias Redirector can achieve this. http://www.komodia.com/products/komodia-redirector/ are there cheaper alternatives?

Comment: In the netfilterdsk documentation http://netfiltersdk.com/help/ProtocolFilters/ it says "It is possible to update object content in dataPartAvailable and return DPCR_UPDATE_AND_BYPASS"

Comment: Asking for a library is an offtopic in SO.

Comment: Actually I didnt ask for a library, but asked if the library netfiltersdk is able to do it according to their documentation. To me it is not clear, and I am interested in what others think

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need not to include any javascript. There is an http section over the user interface. Just write your html code over there and it will show you that code.